# Page displays true after running command: 'webby'

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-8.10, webby

I'm running though the [webby tutorial](http://webby.rubyforge.org/tutorial/) and I get to the part where you run the **webby** command for the first time to generate the website in the /output directory.

I do that, and next I'm told to open output/index.html.   I do so, and the only thing that displays is:

```
true
```

I view the source...and all that is displayed is

```
true
```

This isn't a Budweiser commercial from years past!  This is webby!

I wrote down the commands I used to install webby [here](http://leeand00.tiddlyspot.com/#[[Installing%20Webby]]), but it still doesn't seem to work.

According to the **webby -v** command... I was doing it correctly. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm - did you open output/index.html in a browser? And the "true" that you describe is what you see in your browser...?

Before you ran the `webby` command, did you edit any of the files, especially `content/index.txt`? Can you paste the contents of `content/index.txt` here...?

Did you install `RedCloth` as well as `Webby` or did it install automatically as a dependency? If you run the following command, you can see whether `RedCloth` is installed.

```
gem list RedCloth
```

Comment: leeand00@U101:~/my_site/content$ gem list RedCloth

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

RedCloth (4.1.1)

Comment: Yup that was it.  I installed RedCloth using apt-get but not using gem.